# Write to InstallLog from Installer

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation

How do I write to the InstallLog from a service installer?

I've overridden the `OnBeforeInstall` method of my class (which derives from `System.Configuration.Install.Installer`and now I want to write to the installer log. But I can't see anything that would allow me to do this.

Console.WriteLine will write to the console but not to the log.

Comment: It seems impossible ... at least I haven't found a solution. Here is the word from MSDN on this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/f8ae093d-b70f-4230-9502-bb2007719395/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, there's a property called Context in the Installer class. It has type InstallContext. That type has the method LogMessage(), which I suppose is what you need. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installcontext.logmessage.aspx) for more information about LogMessage() method.

Comment: That's what you can see, but LogMessage does not work unless you run "InstallUtil.exe" as the parent process. Nothing gets logged if you use an MSI or MSIEXEC.

Comment: This does the job if you use installutil directly, although be aware that there is 2 logs InstallUtil.InstallLog and ServiceName.Service.InstallLog, you messages get logged into 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

I just create my own log.

```
public void SetupLog(string sLine) {
     using(StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("c:\\mysetup.log")) 
        w.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} {sLine}");
  }
```